# Who cleans the cleaner fish?

Tags: ethology, ichthyology, symbiosis

Cleaner fish are those fish that eat the dead skin cells and parasites off from other usually larger fish.
( such cleaners include wrasse, cichlids, catfish, shrimp etc )

I wondered if the cleaner fish themselves ever receive this service from others, though understandably it is an added benefit rather than a necessary one for health.